# PySpark: Insert or update dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, upsert

I have two dataframes, DF1 and DF2. DF1 is the master and DF2 is the delta. The data from DF2 should be inserted into DF1 or used to update the DF1 data.

Lets say the DF1 is of the following format:

| id_no | start_date | amount | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 4650 | 22 |
| 2 | 2016-01-02 | 3130 | 45 |
| 1 | 2016-01-03 | 4456 | 22 |
| 2 | 2016-01-15 | 1234 | 45 |

DF2 contains the following:

| id_no | start_date | amount | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 8650 | 52 |
| 2 | 2016-01-02 | 7130 | 65 |
| 1 | 2016-01-06 | 3456 | 20 |
| 2 | 2016-01-20 | 2345 | 19 |
| 3 | 2016-02-02 | 1345 | 19 |

I need to combine the two dataframes such that if the "id_no" and "start date" of DF2 matches DF1, it should be replaced in DF1 and if does not match, it should be inserted into DF1. The "id_no" is not unique.

The expected result:

| id_no | start_date | amount | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 8650 | 52 |
| 2 | 2016-01-02 | 7130 | 65 |
| 1 | 2016-01-03 | 4456 | 22 |
| 2 | 2016-01-15 | 1234 | 45 |
| 1 | 2016-01-06 | 3456 | 20 |
| 2 | 2016-01-20 | 2345 | 19 |
| 3 | 2016-02-02 | 1345 | 19 |

Answer (score 12):

You can join the two data frames on `id_no` and `start_date`, and then `coalesce` the `amount` and `days` column with columns from `df2` coming first:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1.alias('a').join(
    df2.alias('b'), ['id_no', 'start_date'], how='outer'
).select('id_no', 'start_date', 
    f.coalesce('b.amount', 'a.amount').alias('amount'), 
    f.coalesce('b.days', 'a.days').alias('days')
).show()

+-----+----------+------+----+
|id_no|start_date|amount|days|
+-----+----------+------+----+
|    1|2016-01-06|  3456|  20|
|    2|2016-01-20|  2345|  19|
|    1|2016-01-03|  4456|  22|
|    3|2016-02-02|  1345|  19|
|    2|2016-01-15|  1234|  45|
|    1|2016-01-01|  8650|  52|
|    2|2016-01-02|  7130|  65|
+-----+----------+------+----+
```

If you have many more columns:

```py
cols = ['amount', 'days']

df1.alias('a').join(
    df2.alias('b'), ['id_no', 'start_date'], how='outer'
).select('id_no', 'start_date', 
    *(f.coalesce('b.' + col, 'a.' + col).alias(col) for col in cols)
).show()
+-----+----------+------+----+
|id_no|start_date|amount|days|
+-----+----------+------+----+
|    1|2016-01-06|  3456|  20|
|    2|2016-01-20|  2345|  19|
|    1|2016-01-03|  4456|  22|
|    3|2016-02-02|  1345|  19|
|    2|2016-01-15|  1234|  45|
|    1|2016-01-01|  8650|  52|
|    2|2016-01-02|  7130|  65|
+-----+----------+------+----+
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What if the dataframes contain 25 more columns? Should I use coalesce for all the 25 columns?

Comment: You can do it programmatically by looping through the list of columns, `coalesce` `df2` and `df1`, and use the `*` syntax in `select`.

Answer (score 1):

`union` and subsequent `agg` would work.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

grp_by = {'id_no', 'start_date'}
df = df1.union(df2)
df = df.groupby(*grp_by).agg(*[F.first(c).alias(c) for c in set(df.columns)-grp_by])

df.show()
# +-----+----------+------+----+
# |id_no|start_date|amount|days|
# +-----+----------+------+----+
# |    2|2016-01-02|  3130|  45|
# |    1|2016-01-01|  4650|  22|
# |    1|2016-01-03|  4456|  22|
# |    2|2016-01-15|  1234|  45|
# |    3|2016-02-02|  1345|  19|
# |    1|2016-01-06|  3456|  20|
# |    2|2016-01-20|  2345|  19|
# +-----+----------+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Databricks Delta Lake tables, you could use SQL's [`MERGE INTO`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html):

> Merges a set of updates, insertions, and deletions based on a source table into a target Delta table.
> This statement is supported only for Delta Lake tables.

You would just need to create a `new_id` that is a join of `id_no` and `start_date`.

```sql
MERGE INTO df1
USING df2
ON df1.new_id = df2.new_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET df1.amount = df2.amount, df1.days = df2.days
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT *
```