# PySpark: Update column values from dataframe A with dataframe B's values with matching ID

Tags: python, pyspark

Assume we have dfA:

| ID | Scores |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| A | 40 |
| A | 60 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 90 |

and dfB:

| ID | Scores |
| --- | --- |
| A | 60 |
| B | 90 |

Expected OUTPUT:

| ID | Scores |
| --- | --- |
| A | 60 |
| A | 60 |
| A | 60 |
| B | 90 |
| B | 90 |

How can I update the score column in dfA with dfB's score according to matching ID in PySpark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark: Insert or update dataframe with another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007418/pyspark-insert-or-update-dataframe-with-another-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrames

```
df_1
+---+------+
| ID|Scores|
+---+------+
|  A|    20|
|  A|    40|
|  A|    60|
|  B|    10|
|  B|    90|
+---+------+

df_2
+---+------+
| ID|Scores|
+---+------+
|  A|    60|
|  B|    90|
+---+------+
```

1. Rename the `Scores` column name to `old_scores` from *df_1* before joining.

```
df_1 = df_1.withColumnRenamed("Scores", "old_scores")
```

2. Use inner join to match the two DataFrames using the common key column.

```
df = df_1.join(df_2, "ID")
```

3. Drop the `old_scores` column from `df_1`

```
df.drop("old_scores").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+
| ID|Scores|
+---+------+
|  A|    60|
|  A|    60|
|  A|    60|
|  B|    90|
|  B|    90|
+---+------+
```